# run netperf without IP address available

Tags: networking, fedora, dpdk

I have DPDK set up, with two NICs taken over by DPDK, i.e. the interfaces
are not visible to userspace applications.

Now, I need to run netperf/iperf to measure throughput performance of port-to-port
configuration of DPDK, as described here  https://github.com/01org/dpdk-ovs/blob/development/docs/04_Sample_Configurations/00_Phy-Phy.md

However netperf server requires to be bound to the network interface, and netperf client
has to know the netserver's IP address. But since the interfaces were taken
by DPDK, and netperf can't see their IP addresses any longer, how could I
run tests? Is there a way to redirect netperf right in network port,
regardless of IP addressess.

iptables, ebtables.. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going by that diagram, your netperf and netserver should both be on the traffic generator.  On the DPDK host, traffic coming in one interface is simply routed out the other interface by OVS, and back to your generator.  There are a variety of tricks to get your generator to send traffic out on the wire rather than short circuiting over loopback, but they have been addressed here already.

If what you really want to do is have netserver running on the DPDK host, then you simply need to create a virtual interface, attach it to OVS, give it an IP, and direct your netperf traffic to it.